# "Interpolation Toolset" is inactive in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, interpolation

I have ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 installed on my laptop and "Interpolation toolset" and "Raster Interpolation toolset" is Inactive.

How can I get them work?

Comment: Have you installed _and_ enabled the [Spatial Analyst extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_Extensions_in_ArcGIS/018900000002000000/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @Luke, I think the most likely explanation for this is that you do not have the Spatial Analyst installed, licensed and enabled.

If you have 3D Analyst but not Spatial Analyst then the former can also unlock some of the tools in the toolsets mentioned and those tools are listed on this **[page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Analyst_toolbox_licensing/009z000000ww000000/)** from the Online Help.